# Smooth Mayavi Visualization of 3D Points

Tags: python, numpy, mayavi, marching-cubes

It's my first time visualizing in 3D and working with `mayavi` so please forgive my lack of knowledge. 
I have a 3D Numpy which I wanna visualize. The Array represents a voxel grid, so far I tried it with `points3d`, but the visualization doesn't look smooth, here is my code:

```
x, y, z = np.where(voxelGrid >= 100)
s = voxelGrid[voxelGrid >= 100]

z = z*2

mlab.points3d(x, y, z, s, scale_mode='none', color=(1,1,1), mode='sphere', scale_factor=3)
mlab.show()
```

Thats how it looks like: 
[image: My Visualization]

An Thats how I want it too look like: 
[image: Expectation]

What would be the best way to get it smooth like this?
Thank you!!!

Edit: I have found out that I need a marching cube algorithm, how can I do that in python, is there anything in `mayavi` or `vtk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Guys i found a way by using the library scikit-image, it has a very nice and fast function called  measure.marching_cubes_lewiner()

[Marching Cube by scikit](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_marching_cubes.html)